# Python unittest patching is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have the following project structure:

```
root/
|-mylib/
  |-tests/
  | |-__init__.py
  | |-test_trend.py
  |-__init__.py
  |-data.py
  |-trend.py
```

In `trend.py`:

```
from mylib.data import get_item

def get_trend(input: str):
    item = get_item(input)
    return f"Trend is: {item}"
```

Inside `data.py`:

```
def get_item(id):
    print("ORIGINAL")
    return get_item_from_db(id)
```

#### Testing

I want to test `get_trend` in isolation, therefore I patch `get_item` inside: `test_trend.py`:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from mylib.trend import get_trend

def p__get_item(input):
    return 0

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("mylib.data.get_item", new=p__get_item)
    def test_trend(self):
        v = get_trend()
        self.assertEqual(v, "Trend is: 0")
```

But when I run the tests (the command is run from inside the `root` directory):

```
python -m unittest discover
```

I see that the log shows that the original `get_item` is called. The test is failing of course.

What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Attempt 1

If I try this other flavor of the `patch` APIL

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("mylib.data.get_item")
    def test_trend(self, mocked_fun):
        mocked_fun.return_value = 0
        v = get_trend()
        self.assertEqual(v, "Trend is: 0")
```

It still does not work. In the console log I can see `ORIGINAL` being printed and the test fails.

#### Experiment 1

If I change the `target` in `@patch` to a non existing attribute like:

```
@patch("mylib.data.non_existing", new=p__get_item)
```

I actually get an error from the library saying the module does not contain such attribute. So, it seems like `mylib.data.get_item` is correctly being targeted, but still the patching is not happening.

Comment: You have to patch the object where it is used, not where it comes from. Since you imported it locally, just patch `get_stuff`. But actually your test tests a mock and wouldn't be very helpful.

Comment: But that is what I am doing. I am patching it inside the test file where I am using it. Can you post an answer with the complete code please? I feel i am not getting your point, thank you

Comment: I wonder if its easier to just mock the function? also maybe you meant to use `new_callable` instead of `new`?

Comment: My example is simple just to get a hack of how this thing is working, in this example of course it would be just easier to do that, but I need to understand how this patching works...

Comment: I made some edits, please consider them, thanks

Comment: I'm not talking about where your place the `patch` call, I'm talking about the target of `patch` (the first argument).

Comment: I think you submitted the wrong code. The traceback shows different code being executed from the one you posted

Comment: Nope, the trackback is the same.  I also expected a new one with the change, but nope, same

Comment: The test works fine for me. Please update the code and the traceback so they match.

Comment: Hi all. apologies, I have edited the code to reflect what is going on and removed some noise. Essentially the problem is that the patching is not happening as the original function is called.

Comment: Add it as a parameter in the function definition and use it to return the value. So, your function definition should be: `def test_trend(self,mocked_func):` and inside the body use it to return the value you want inside get_trend..

Comment: Tried it... does not work. See updated question

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

`get_item` is called in `mylib.trend` module, however, you patched it in `mylib.data` module, which is the wrong place. `patch` works by replacing objects on `import`. In this case, you want to patch `get_item` inside `mylib.trend` module not `mylib.data`.

## Solution

```py
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("mylib.trend.get_item")
    def test_trend(self, mocked_get_item):
        mocked_get_item.return_value = 0
        ...
```

## Notes

Further explanation on where to patch can be found on the official python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).